# Azure devops pipeline restAPI How to pass varible with SourceFolder for CopyFiles Task , self hosted agent in container

Tags: docker, api, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-pipelines

my set up is as follow
I have hosted agent that as first job copies files from the self-hosted agent which is started as a docker container

the hosted pipeline is triggered with pipeline "run" rest API :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run%20pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

this is how the body looks like now :

```
"resources": {
        "repositories:": {
            "self": {
                "refName": "refs/heads/my_branch"
            }
        }
    }
```

it is working great.
now the part of the hosted pipeline looks like this :

```
- job: self_hosted_connect
  timeoutInMinutes: 10
  pool: Default
  steps:
  - task: CopyFiles@2
    inputs:
      SourceFolder: '/home/copy_dir'
      Contents: '**'
      TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
```

also, work great.

My questions are :

1. I like to send in the "run" rest API another parameter that contains the SourceFolder path
   so that the CopyFiles task will be dynamic and not have hardcode SourceFolder path
2. When i run the self-hosted agent from docker how do i tell the self-hosted agent to include the directory outside its working dir? so the pipeline will not fail with the error :

   #[error]Unhandled: Not found SourceFolder: /home/copy_dir

**UPDATE**
i updated the request to :

```
{
    "resources": {
        "repositories:": {
            "self": {
                "refName": "refs/heads/my_branch"
            }
        }
    },
    "templateParameters": {
        "Folderpath":"{/home/foo/my_dir}"
    }
}
```

but I'm getting an error:

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "innerException": null,
    "message": "Unexpected parameter 'Folderpath'",
    "typeName": "Microsoft.Azure.Pipelines.WebApi.PipelineValidationException, Microsoft.Azure.Pipelines.WebApi",
    "typeKey": "PipelineValidationException",
    "errorCode": 0,
    "eventId": 3000
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> send in the "run" rest API another parameter that contains the SourceFolder path
> We can use [runtime parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script) in pipeline.

YAML sample:

```
parameters:
- name: Folderpath
  displayName: 'configure Folder path'
  type: string
  default: {SourceFolder path}

steps:
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '${{ parameters.Folderpath}}'
    Contents: '**'
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
```

Request URL:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/runs?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

Request Body:

```
{
    "resources":{
        "repositories":{
            "self":{"refName":"refs/heads/{my_branch}"
            }
         }
    },
    "templateParameters": {
        "Folderpath":"{SourceFolder path}"
        }
}
```

> how do i tell the self-hosted agent to include the directory outside its working dir?

We can copy the local folder or azure DevOps [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to define the source folder.

**Update1**

We should define the parameter in the YAML build, if not, we will get the error Unexpected parameter 'Folderpath'"

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

as i like it to take from the real path (the one i pass in the request ) on the disc where the self-hosted docker
running and not relative to the docker working dir, so now it gives me this error :

```
[error]Unhandled: Not found SourceFolder: /azp/agent/_work/1/s/{/home/copy_dir}
```

where /azp is the docker working dir

i configured docker from this  link :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops

Comment: Thanks i will try it and report

Comment: Hi @user63898, Feel free to let me know if the answer could give you some help. If you still have any questions, I will still be here to help you

Comment: Thanks im getting error :Unexpected parameter 'Folderpath'"
please see my updated question

Comment: Hi @user63898, I have updated the answer, please check it. We need to make sure that the parameter folder path is already defined in yaml.

Comment: Thanks but now im getting this error :
[error]Unhandled: Not found SourceFolder: /azp/agent/_work/1/s/{/home/t/copy_dir}
as i told you I'm running now the docker self hosted agent and the working dir is /azp

Comment: Hi @user63898, Sorry for my mistake, I have update the answer screenshot, we should not add {} in the request body path. The real path on the disc is local path, right? We should add the full path, such as 'E:/agent/_work/1/s'

Comment: Hi @user63898, does this work now? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here

Comment: Yes it is working, but the part where i run Fastlane using script  failing badly 
open a new ticket?

Comment: thanks for your help , see if you can help here : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63801672/fastlane-getting-security-seckeychainitemimport-the-specified-keychain-coul

Comment: Hi @user63898, You could accept the answer. In this case, others could directly find the useful solution, and my colleague is investigating that ticket, he will help you resolve the issue. Thanks.

Comment: question, can i ssh directly to the agent somehow to test there the commands?

Comment: We can add task and enter the commands, then check the result.